Does Coarse Grit reduce damage taken from Chaos's Doomed Boons?
The description for Demeter's Coarse Grit Boon reads:

While you have at least 6 Earth, you cannot take more than 15 damage per hit.

Chaos' Doomed Boons have the effect:

You have 120 seconds to clear three encounters, or get hit for -500 Life.

Does Coarse Grit's 15 HP damage limiting effect work on Chaos' Doomed curse?

Coarse Grit seems to now be Frosty Veneer and works on Water instead of Earth.

Well, Breath of Eros doesn't treat "Cost to enter Chaos's Room" as "damage to be turned into healing".
If Coarse Grit, now Frosty Veneer, are similar and don't protect from Chaos damage nor Nemesis Hits, I don't think it'd count for Chaos's Dooms either.
But maybe it's different. Really hard get the boons and rooms to line up, so here's a guess for now.
